# CCA (Canonical Correspondence Analysis) - Which version of the dataset is more adequate?

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, dataset, canonical-correlation, correspondence-analysis

I'm currently working on a dataset of +400 samples, with 2 quantitative variables (salinity and depth) and 2 qualitative ones (sequencing method performed and nature of the sample, sediment or water)
[image: 2 different versions of my dataset (just structre example, no real data)]

**My objective is to understand which variable(s) influence my phylum abundance.** 
I decided to use CCA and it works well, but now i have a big doubt. One of the sequencing method considered is Illumina, so the number of sequences obtained for those samples is incredibly high compared to the others (sequenced with Sanger or 454). **Is that a problem with CCA if I use % abundance** as shown in the first table? In this way I solve the "problem" of the big difference in the absolute number of sequences